# NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' net/protocol.rb

Tags: ruby, http

I have upgraded an app to ruby from 2.1 to 2.4 and I got the following error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for {:read_timeout=>60, :continue_timeout=>nil, :debug_output=>nil}:Hash
Did you mean?  <
from /Users/me/.rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:219:in `writing'
```

It seems that something has changed in the net/http library. Anyone knows what changed and/or how to fix it?

```
def writing
  @written_bytes = 0
  @debug_output << '<- ' if @debug_output
  yield
  @debug_output << "\n" if @debug_output
  bytes = @written_bytes
  @written_bytes = nil
  bytes
end
```

The exception is raised at the first `@debug_output` line.

Comment: Can you show us the code where this is happening because as the error mentions `Hash` does not have a `<<` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to assure to have gem versions compatible with ruby 2.4. There are several issues similar to yours:

- [Fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb/commit/5bd70b72962081e46c7b22a39d00b7660d0ad30e)
- [Bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5268)
- [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/683) (not the same but similar)

Comment: Thanks the issue is caused by the fakeweb gem. I removed it and the problem disappeared. 
Note that the fakeweb gem does not have any recent release so I just diched it.

Comment: You can use the git version, as noted in [this issue](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb/issues/62)

Comment: It was not used extensively, so removing it is just a good thing. Thanks

Comment: In my case we were including both fakeweb and webmock. We weren't really using fakeweb, so removing it and updating webmock solved it.